# Same length textviews not aligned

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

I am displaying a couple of textviews inside a ListView component. My issue is that textview's text is not aligned between rows despite having the same length. I am attaching an image to make the issue clear.

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKyLo.png)

It is not quite visible but its still annoying and I cannot find why its happening.
The xml layout file of the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_date"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17sp"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_temp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Default android font is not monospaced (each symbol can have different width) so having same text length does not imply same width of each TextView.

Comment: Use monospased font

Comment: Thank you both, using a monospaced font fixed the issue.